# Crystal Reports: Sumarize formula field

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to have a formula field like the following

```
If Count(Employees.Trainings, Employees.EmployeeID)>=1 Then
   Employees.EmployeeID
Else
   Null
```

My goal is to do a count on this formula so that I know how many Employees have completed at least one training.
Apparenlty this is not possible in Crystal Reports.
Is there a workaround?
I would like my report to look something like this:

```
Department   Employees  Sum(days)  Employees who have at least one training
Department A      25       120                                        20 
Department B      12       34                                         10
```

I miss the last column.
My report is grouped by the Department and Employee ID. Thank you!

Comment: Question is not that clear..can you show how design looks like and how you would like to have

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I edited my question.

Comment: ok understood the issue... now question is do you want to display employee id who completed more than 1 training are do you want to show only those records which has more than one training... because as per your example it looks like you are just showing the count of trainings

Comment: No, I don;t need to display any ID or name whatsoever. Only the counts.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to create helper query to calculate some aggregates and link this query in CR.

If this not possible, you could create SQL expression field to find inner count - this can be somewhat hard, if you have additional conditions, filtering employees.

Next possibility is to use subreport to calculate count of employees with training, exchange data between main and subreport using shared variables and summarize them using print-time formulas.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a total noobie with crystal reports so I did try to use subreports and get how many training the employees have completed. But I am not sure how to count the people how have more that one training and display that as a count on the group header above (department group) the employee group.
I also did tried to add a command (I guess this is what you mean by "helper query to calculate some aggregates") an I am currently working on this way.

Comment: "Helper query" means view in database - not Crystal database command.

Answer (score 0):

Best and simple way that I advice is to extend to what you have already done.

since you have already grouped by the `Department` and `Employee ID`

Place training's in detail along with other fields, Now take the sum of training's in group footer of the group that you want to display, This will give you number of training's  along with employees and number of days.

```
if employeehastrainings //use condition (as I am not aware how is your database data for this field )to check trainings are there are not..here you don't what kind of training just needed whether training is presenet are not
then 1
else 0
```

This sum in footer will give you number of training's from `0` to any number.

Now you just supress the records that have training's  equal to or less than count of training's.

go to supress of group footer and write below formula

```
If sum(Employees.Trainings, Employees.EmployeeID)<=1 Then
true
else 
false
```

This will only show those employees that are that have training's more than 1 and rest all will be supressed.

try and let me know

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer and sorry for the late reply. Your solution (if I understood and did everything right) displays the name of the employees who have trainings>=1. However I don't need the names. I only need to know how many they are. If it helps in my report I also have the number of the trainings they have completed in a "count" summary field on the level of the Employee Group .Is there a way to count again this summary field  but for the Department Group?

Comment: There is a way but unfortunately today is day off for me so I can't access crystal report but tomorrow when I will be in office will test and post the solution.

Comment: No worries! This is one project of many. However I wanted to add that I did manage to get the count of the employees with more that 1 training in the employee group, with the "Initialize-Count-Reset" formula fields/method. Is there a way to "move" this count to the group above ("department")?

Comment: above department means in deparment header?

Comment: exaclty, whish is the first group.

Comment: Actually when you use a `Initialize-Count-Reset` then you can't get the data in group header but if you really wish to then one way is to replicate the same grouping option in sub report and place the sub report above the group headers and then pass the final value to group header of main report... but by this your performance can degrade